# Write a program that always prints N when it is shifted N times up the ASCII alphabet

Tags: code-challenge, number, source-layout, printable-ascii

Write a program using only [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) that takes no input. For reference, here are the 95 printable ASCII characters in order:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

When your program is run it should print `0` (plus an optional trailing newline) to stdout, then terminate normally.

When each character in your program is replaced by the character N spaces to its right in printable ASCII, looping around from `~` to space, the resulting printable ASCII string will *ideally* be a program runnable in the same language that takes no input and outputs N (plus an optional trailing newline) to stdout, then terminates normally, for N = 1 to 94.

For example, if your original program was

```
@Cat~(88 !)
```

running it should output `0` and shifting all the characters up the printable ASCII scale by one

```
ADbu )99!"*
```

should result in another program that outputs `1`. Doing so again will ideally result in another program that outputs `2`

```
BEcv!*::"#+
```

and so on with 3 and 4, etc. up to the point of shifting 94 times

```
?B`s}'77~ (
```

which ideally is a program that outputs `94`.

The relief is that this is only the ideal behavior. Your program and its 94 derivatives do not all need to work, but the more that consecutively do from the start the better. (Programs that do not work may have any behavior whatsoever.)

## Scoring

Your score is the number of *consecutive* programs starting from the original (the one that outputs `0`) that do work, i.e. correctly output their corresponding N. The answer with the highest score (a maximum of 95) wins. If there's a tie then the program with the shortest length in bytes wins.

For example, if `@Cat~(88 !)` output `0` and `ADbu )99!"*` output `1` but `BEcv!*::"#+` errored, then your score would be 2. It's 2 even if `` ?B`s}'77~ ( `` accurately outputs `94` and even if all the programs for N = 30 to 40 worked. Only the *consecutive* number of working programs, starting at zero, are counted.

## Notes

- To combat potential contention and loopholes, competing answers must output their numbers in decimal with no leading zeroes or signs or decimal points (i.e. plain `0` `1` `2` ... `94`).
- Languages that use different bases or number formats are allowed but are not eligible to win.
- The presence of an optional trailing newline does not need to be consistent across programs.
- Functions and REPL commands are not allowed, only full programs.

Comment: Is it OK to have `ans = 0`?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Sorry but to go along with the first note it should be plain `0` printed to stdout. You can do a noncompetitive answer though.

Comment: I think we should repost this problem with the following two additional restrictions: 1) The program must be written in a language whose compiler or interpreter does not ignore invalid syntax without explicit comment delimiters, and 2) every iteration of the program must use an explicit print statement to write out the answer. This would make the challenge more meaningful and, I would suspect, result in more answers in C-like languages, which I assume was what you desired from this challenge.

Comment: As it is, all the answers seem to be some variation of "repeat the same statement 95 times except 94 of them are ignored due to some syntactic quirk". That's not interesting.

Comment: @JoeZ. Yeah. When writing it I didn't consider that type of program. You're welcome to post a new similar challenge.

Answer (score 30):

### [Ook!](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!), 95 programs, <s>19992</s> 14066 bytes

```
Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook?Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook.Ook?Ook.Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook?Ook!Ook.Ook?Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook!Ook.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ}.NJl.NJ}.NJl.NJl.NJ}.NJl.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ_.NJ}.NJ_.NJl.NJ}.NJ_.NJl.NJ_.NJl-)>l-)>l-)>l-)\l-)Kl-)\l-)Kl-)Kl-)\l-)Kl-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)>l-)\l-)>l-)Kl-)\l-)Kl-)Kl-)Kl-)Kl-)Kl-)Kl-)>l-)Kl-)>l-)Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg;Kkg*Kkg;Kkg*Kkg*Kkg;Kkg*Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg|Kkg;Kkg|Kkg*Kkg;Kkg*Kkg*Kkg|Kkg*JF[*JF[*JF[*JFy*JFh*JFy*JFh*JFh*JFy*JFh*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JF[*JFy*JF[*JFh*JFy*JF[*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JFh*JF[*JFh)%Gh)%Xh)%:h)%:h)%:h)%Xh)%Gh)%Gh)%Gh)%Gh)%Gh)%Xh)%Gh)%Gh)%:h)%Xh)%Gh)%Gh)%Xh)%Gh)%Xh)%:h)%Gh)%Xh)%Xh)%:h)%Gh)%Xh)%:h)%:h)%:h)%Gh)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%:h)%Ggc&Ggc7GgcxGgcxGgcxGgc7Ggc&Ggc&Ggc&Ggc&Ggc&Ggc7Ggc&Ggc&GgcxGgc7Ggc&Ggc&Ggc7Ggc&Ggc7GgcxGgc&Ggc7Ggc7GgcxGgc&Ggc7GgcxGgc&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBu&FBd&FBu&FBd&FBd&FBu&FBd&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBu&FBW&FBd&FBu&FBd&FBd&FBW&FBd&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBW&FBd%!Cd%!Td%!6d%!6d%!6d%!Td%!Cd%!Cd%!Cd%!Cd%!Cd%!Td%!Cd%!Cd%!6d%!Td%!Cd%!Cd%!Td%!Cd%!Td%!6d%!Cd%!Td%!Td%!6d%!Cd%!Td%!6d%!6d%!6d%!Cd%!6d%!6d%!6d%!6d%!6d%!6d%!6d%!Cc_tCc_tCc_tCc_3Cc_"Cc_3Cc_"Cc_"Cc_3Cc_"Cc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_3Cc_tCc_"Cc_3Cc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_tCc_"Cc_"Cc_"Cc_tCc_"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>q"B>`"B>q"B>`"B>`"B>q"B>`"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>S"B>q"B>S"B>`"B>q"B>`"B>`"B>S"B>`"B>`"B>`"B>S"B>`!|?`!|P`!|2`!|2`!|2`!|P`!|?`!|?`!|?`!|?`!|?`!|P`!|?`!|?`!|2`!|P`!|?`!|?`!|P`!|?`!|P`!|2`!|?`!|P`!|P`!|2`!|?`!|P`!|2`!|2`!|2`!|?`!|?`!|?`!|2`!|?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[/?_[}?_[/?_[}?_[}?_[/?_[}?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[/?_[p?_[}?_[/?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[p?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[}?_[p?_[}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:m}>:\}>:m}>:\}>:\}>:m}>:\}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:O}>:m}>:O}>:\}>:m}>:\}>:\}>:O}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:\}>:O}>:\|x;\|xL\|x.\|x.\|x.\|xL\|x;\|x;\|x;\|x;\|x;\|xL\|x;\|x;\|x.\|xL\|x;\|x;\|xL\|x;\|xL\|x.\|x;\|xL\|xL\|x.\|x;\|xL\|x.\|x;\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x.\|x;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[W+;[Wy;[W+;[Wy;[Wy;[W+;[Wy;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[W+;[Wl;[Wy;[W+;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wy;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wl;[Wy:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6iy:6Xy:6iy:6Xy:6Xy:6iy:6Xy:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6iy:6Ky:6Xy:6iy:6Xy:6Xy:6Xy:6Xy:6Ky:6Xy:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Ky:6Xxt7XxtHXxt*Xxt*Xxt*XxtHXxt7Xxt7Xxt7Xxt7Xxt7XxtHXxt7Xxt7Xxt*XxtHXxt7Xxt7XxtHXxt7XxtHXxt*Xxt7XxtHXxtHXxt*Xxt7XxtHXxt*Xxt7Xxt*Xxt*Xxt*Xxt*Xxt*Xxt7WSh7WSh7WSh7WS'7WSu7WS'7WSu7WSu7WS'7WSu7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSh7WS'7WSh7WSu7WS'7WSh7WSh7WSh7WSu7WSu7WSu7WSu7WSu7WSh7WSu62Gu62Gu62Gu62eu62Tu62eu62Tu62Tu62eu62Tu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62Gu62eu62Gu62Tu62eu62Tu62Tu62Tu62Tu62Gu62Tu62Tu62Tu62Tu62Tu62Gu62Ttp3TtpDTtp&Ttp&Ttp&TtpDTtp3Ttp3Ttp3Ttp3Ttp3TtpDTtp3Ttp3Ttp&TtpDTtp3Ttp3TtpDTtp3TtpDTtp&Ttp3TtpDTtpDTtp&Ttp3TtpDTtp3Ttp3Ttp&Ttp3Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp&Ttp3SOd3SOd3SOd3SO#3SOq3SO#3SOq3SOq3SO#3SOq3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOd3SO#3SOd3SOq3SO#3SOd3SOd3SOd3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOq3SOd3SOq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.aq2.Pq2.aq2.Pq2.Pq2.aq2.Pq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.aq2.Cq2.Pq2.aq2.Pq2.Pq2.Pq2.Pq2.Pq2.Pq2.Cq2.Pq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Cq2.Ppl/Ppl@Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl@Ppl/Ppl/Ppl/Ppl/Ppl/Ppl@Ppl/Ppl/Ppl"Ppl@Ppl/Ppl/Ppl@Ppl/Ppl@Ppl"Ppl/Ppl@Ppl@Ppl"Ppl/Ppl@Ppl/Ppl/Ppl"Ppl/Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl"Ppl/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK~/OKm/OK~/OKm/OKm/OK~/OKm/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK`/OK~/OK`/OKm/OK~/OK`/OKm/OK`/OK`/OK`/OKm.*?m.*?m.*?m.*]m.*Lm.*]m.*Lm.*Lm.*]m.*Lm.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*?m.*]m.*?m.*Lm.*]m.*Lm.*Lm.*Lm.*Lm.*Lm.*Lm.*?m.*Lm.*?m.*?m.*?m.*Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh<Llh+Llh<Llh+Llh+Llh<Llh+Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh}Llh<Llh}Llh+Llh<Llh}Llh+KG\+KG\+KG\+KGz+KGi+KGz+KGi+KGi+KGz+KGi+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KG\+KGz+KG\+KGi+KGz+KG\+KGi+KGi+KGi+KGi+KGi+KGi+KGi+KG\+KGi*&;i*&;i*&;i*&Yi*&Hi*&Yi*&Hi*&Hi*&Yi*&Hi*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&;i*&Yi*&;i*&Hi*&Yi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&;i*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&Hi*&;i*&Hhd'Hhd8HhdyHhdyHhdyHhd8Hhd'Hhd'Hhd'Hhd'Hhd'Hhd8Hhd'Hhd'HhdyHhd8Hhd'Hhd'Hhd8Hhd'Hhd8HhdyHhd'Hhd8Hhd8HhdyHhd'Hhd8HhdyHhdyHhdyHhd'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCv'GCe'GCv'GCe'GCe'GCv'GCe'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCv'GCX'GCe'GCv'GCe'GCe'GCX'GCe'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCX'GCe&"De&"Ue&"7e&"7e&"7e&"Ue&"De&"De&"De&"De&"De&"Ue&"De&"De&"7e&"Ue&"De&"De&"Ue&"De&"Ue&"7e&"De&"Ue&"Ue&"7e&"De&"Ue&"7e&"7e&"7e&"De&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"7e&"Dd`uDd`uDd`uDd`4Dd`#Dd`4Dd`#Dd`#Dd`4Dd`#Dd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`4Dd`uDd`#Dd`4Dd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`uDd`#Dd`uDd`#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?r#C?a#C?r#C?a#C?a#C?r#C?a#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?T#C?r#C?T#C?a#C?r#C?a#C?a#C?T#C?a#C?T#C?a"}@a"}Qa"}3a"}3a"}3a"}Qa"}@a"}@a"}@a"}@a"}@a"}Qa"}@a"}@a"}3a"}Qa"}@a"}@a"}Qa"}@a"}Qa"}3a"}@a"}Qa"}Qa"}3a"}@a"}Qa"}3a"}3a"}3a"}@a"}3a"}@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\0@`\~@`\0@`\~@`\~@`\0@`\~@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\0@`\q@`\~@`\0@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\q@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\~@`\q@`\~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;n~?;]~?;n~?;]~?;]~?;n~?;]~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;P~?;n~?;P~?;]~?;n~?;]~?;]~?;P~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;]~?;P~?;]}y<]}yM]}y/]}y/]}y/]}yM]}y<]}y<]}y<]}y<]}y<]}yM]}y<]}y<]}y/]}yM]}y<]}y<]}yM]}y<]}yM]}y/]}y<]}yM]}yM]}y/]}y<]}yM]}y/]}y<]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y/]}y<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\X,<\Xz<\X,<\Xz<\Xz<\X,<\Xz<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\X,<\Xm<\Xz<\X,<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xm<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xz<\Xm<\Xz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7jz;7Yz;7jz;7Yz;7Yz;7jz;7Yz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7jz;7Lz;7Yz;7jz;7Yz;7Yz;7Yz;7Yz;7Lz;7Yz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Lz;7Yyu8YyuIYyu+Yyu+Yyu+YyuIYyu8Yyu8Yyu8Yyu8Yyu8YyuIYyu8Yyu8Yyu+YyuIYyu8Yyu8YyuIYyu8YyuIYyu+Yyu8YyuIYyuIYyu+Yyu8YyuIYyu+Yyu8Yyu+Yyu+Yyu+Yyu+Yyu+Yyu+Yyu+Yyu8XTi8XTi8XTi8XT(8XTv8XT(8XTv8XTv8XT(8XTv8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTi8XT(8XTi8XTv8XT(8XTi8XTi8XTi8XTv8XTv8XTv8XTi8XTv73Hv73Hv73Hv73fv73Uv73fv73Uv73Uv73fv73Uv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73Hv73fv73Hv73Uv73fv73Uv73Uv73Uv73Uv73Hv73Uv73Uv73Uv73Hv73Uuq4UuqEUuq'Uuq'Uuq'UuqEUuq4Uuq4Uuq4Uuq4Uuq4UuqEUuq4Uuq4Uuq'UuqEUuq4Uuq4UuqEUuq4UuqEUuq'Uuq4UuqEUuqEUuq'Uuq4UuqEUuq'Uuq4Uuq4Uuq4Uuq'Uuq4TPe4TPe4TPe4TP$4TPr4TP$4TPr4TPr4TP$4TPr4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPe4TP$4TPe4TPr4TP$4TPe4TPe4TPe4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPr4TPe4TPr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/br3/Qr3/br3/Qr3/Qr3/br3/Qr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/br3/Dr3/Qr3/br3/Qr3/Qr3/Qr3/Qr3/Qr3/Qr3/Dr3/Qr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Dr3/Qqm0QqmAQqm#Qqm#Qqm#QqmAQqm0Qqm0Qqm0Qqm0Qqm0QqmAQqm0Qqm0Qqm#QqmAQqm0Qqm0QqmAQqm0QqmAQqm#Qqm0QqmAQqmAQqm#Qqm0QqmAQqm0Qqm0Qqm#Qqm0Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm#Qqm0PLa0PLa0PLa0PL 0PLn0PL 0PLn0PLn0PL 0PLn0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PL 0PLa0PLn0PL 0PLa0PLn0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLa0PLn/+@n/+@n/+@n/+^n/+Mn/+^n/+Mn/+Mn/+^n/+Mn/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+^n/+@n/+Mn/+^n/+Mn/+Mn/+Mn/+Mn/+Mn/+Mn/+@n/+Mn/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+@n/+Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi=Mmi,Mmi=Mmi,Mmi,Mmi=Mmi,Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi=Mmi~Mmi,Mmi=Mmi~Mmi~Mmi~Mmi,LH],LH],LH],LH{,LHj,LH{,LHj,LHj,LH{,LHj,LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH],LH{,LH],LHj,LH{,LH],LHj,LHj,LHj,LHj,LHj,LH],LHj+'<j+'<j+'<j+'Zj+'Ij+'Zj+'Ij+'Ij+'Zj+'Ij+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'<j+'Zj+'<j+'Ij+'Zj+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'<j+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'Ij+'<j+'IiezIiezIiezIie9Iie(Iie9Iie(Iie(Iie9Iie(IiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIiezIie9IiezIie(Iie9Iie(Iie(Iie(Iie(Iie(Iie(IiezIie(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDw(HDf(HDw(HDf(HDf(HDw(HDf(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDY(HDw(HDY(HDf(HDw(HDY(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDf(HDY(HDf'#Ef'#Vf'#8f'#8f'#8f'#Vf'#Ef'#Ef'#Ef'#Ef'#Ef'#Vf'#Ef'#Ef'#8f'#Vf'#Ef'#Ef'#Vf'#Ef'#Vf'#8f'#Ef'#Vf'#Vf'#8f'#Ef'#Vf'#8f'#8f'#8f'#Ef'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#8f'#EeavEeavEeavEea5Eea$Eea5Eea$Eea$Eea5Eea$EeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEea5EeavEea$Eea5EeavEeavEeavEeavEeavEea$EeavEeavEeavEea$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@s$D@b$D@s$D@b$D@b$D@s$D@b$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@s$D@U$D@b$D@s$D@b$D@b$D@U$D@b$D@U$D@U$D@U$D@b#~Ab#~Rb#~4b#~4b#~4b#~Rb#~Ab#~Ab#~Ab#~Ab#~Ab#~Rb#~Ab#~Ab#~4b#~Rb#~Ab#~Ab#~Rb#~Ab#~Rb#~4b#~Ab#~Rb#~Rb#~4b#~Ab#~Rb#~4b#~4b#~4b#~Ab#~4b#~4b#~4b#~Aa]rAa]rAa]rAa]1Aa] Aa]1Aa] Aa] Aa]1Aa] Aa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]1Aa]rAa] Aa]1Aa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa]rAa] Aa] Aa] Aa] Aa] Aa] Aa] Aa]rAa] @<Q @<Q @<Q @<o @<^ @<o @<^ @<^ @<o @<^ @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<Q @<o @<Q @<^ @<o @<^ @<^ @<Q @<^ @<^ @<^ @<^ @<^ @<^ @<^ @<Q @<^~z=^~zN^~z0^~z0^~z0^~zN^~z=^~z=^~z=^~z=^~z=^~zN^~z=^~z=^~z0^~zN^~z=^~z=^~zN^~z=^~zN^~z0^~z=^~zN^~zN^~z0^~z=^~zN^~z0^~z=^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z0^~z=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Y-=]Y{=]Y-=]Y{=]Y{=]Y-=]Y{=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Y-=]Yn=]Y{=]Y-=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Yn=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Y{=]Yn=]Y{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8k{<8Z{<8k{<8Z{<8Z{<8k{<8Z{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8k{<8M{<8Z{<8k{<8Z{<8Z{<8Z{<8Z{<8M{<8Z{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8M{<8Zzv9ZzvJZzv,Zzv,Zzv,ZzvJZzv9Zzv9Zzv9Zzv9Zzv9ZzvJZzv9Zzv9Zzv,ZzvJZzv9Zzv9ZzvJZzv9ZzvJZzv,Zzv9ZzvJZzvJZzv,Zzv9ZzvJZzv,Zzv9Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv,Zzv9YUj9YUj9YUj9YU)9YUw9YU)9YUw9YUw9YU)9YUw9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUj9YU)9YUj9YUw9YU)9YUj9YUj9YUj9YUw9YUj9YUw84Iw84Iw84Iw84gw84Vw84gw84Vw84Vw84gw84Vw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84Iw84gw84Iw84Vw84gw84Vw84Vw84Vw84Vw84Iw84Vw84Iw84Vvr5VvrFVvr(Vvr(Vvr(VvrFVvr5Vvr5Vvr5Vvr5Vvr5VvrFVvr5Vvr5Vvr(VvrFVvr5Vvr5VvrFVvr5VvrFVvr(Vvr5VvrFVvrFVvr(Vvr5VvrFVvr(Vvr5Vvr(Vvr5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQ%5UQs5UQ%5UQs5UQs5UQ%5UQs5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQ%5UQf5UQs5UQ%5UQf5UQf5UQf5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQs5UQf5UQs40Es40Es40Es40cs40Rs40cs40Rs40Rs40cs40Rs40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40Es40cs40Es40Rs40cs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Es40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Rs40Es40Rrn1RrnBRrn$Rrn$Rrn$RrnBRrn1Rrn1Rrn1Rrn1Rrn1RrnBRrn1Rrn1Rrn$RrnBRrn1Rrn1RrnBRrn1RrnBRrn$Rrn1RrnBRrnBRrn$Rrn1RrnBRrn1Rrn1Rrn$Rrn1Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn$Rrn1QMb1QMb1QMb1QM!1QMo1QM!1QMo1QMo1QM!1QMo1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QM!1QMb1QMo1QM!1QMb1QMo1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMb1QMo0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,_o0,No0,_o0,No0,No0,_o0,No0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,_o0,Ao0,No0,_o0,No0,No0,No0,No0,No0,No0,Ao0,No0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Ao0,Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj>Nnj-Nnj>Nnj-Nnj-Nnj>Nnj-Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj>Nnj Nnj-Nnj>Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj Nnj-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI|-MIk-MI|-MIk-MIk-MI|-MIk-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI^-MI|-MI^-MIk-MI|-MI^-MIk-MIk-MIk-MI^-MIk,(=k,(=k,(=k,([k,(Jk,([k,(Jk,(Jk,([k,(Jk,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,(=k,([k,(=k,(Jk,([k,(Jk,(Jk,(Jk,(Jk,(Jk,(Jk,(=k,(Jk,(Jk,(Jk,(=k,(Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf:Jjf)Jjf:Jjf)Jjf)Jjf:Jjf)Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf{Jjf:Jjf{Jjf)Jjf:Jjf)Jjf)Jjf)Jjf)Jjf{Jjf)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEx)IEg)IEx)IEg)IEg)IEx)IEg)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEZ)IEx)IEZ)IEg)IEx)IEZ)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEg)IEZ)IEg($Fg($Wg($9g($9g($9g($Wg($Fg($Fg($Fg($Fg($Fg($Wg($Fg($Fg($9g($Wg($Fg($Fg($Wg($Fg($Wg($9g($Fg($Wg($Wg($9g($Fg($Wg($9g($9g($9g($Fg($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($9g($Ffb%Ffb6FfbwFfbwFfbwFfb6Ffb%Ffb%Ffb%Ffb%Ffb%Ffb6Ffb%Ffb%FfbwFfb6Ffb%Ffb%Ffb6Ffb%Ffb6FfbwFfb%Ffb6Ffb6FfbwFfb%Ffb6Ffb%Ffb%FfbwFfb%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAt%EAc%EAt%EAc%EAc%EAt%EAc%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAt%EAV%EAc%EAt%EAc%EAc%EAV%EAc%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAV%EAc$ Bc$ Sc$ 5c$ 5c$ 5c$ Sc$ Bc$ Bc$ Bc$ Bc$ Bc$ Sc$ Bc$ Bc$ 5c$ Sc$ Bc$ Bc$ Sc$ Bc$ Sc$ 5c$ Bc$ Sc$ Sc$ 5c$ Bc$ Sc$ 5c$ 5c$ 5c$ Bc$ 5c$ 5c$ 5c$ 5c$ 5c$ Bb^sBb^sBb^sBb^2Bb^!Bb^2Bb^!Bb^!Bb^2Bb^!Bb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^2Bb^sBb^!Bb^2Bb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^sBb^!Bb^!Bb^!Bb^!Bb^!Bb^sBb^!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=p!A=_!A=p!A=_!A=_!A=p!A=_!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=R!A=p!A=R!A=_!A=p!A=_!A=_!A=R!A=_!A=_!A=_!A=_!A=_!A=R!A=_ {>_ {O_ {1_ {1_ {1_ {O_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {O_ {>_ {>_ {1_ {O_ {>_ {>_ {O_ {>_ {O_ {1_ {>_ {O_ {O_ {1_ {>_ {O_ {1_ {1_ {1_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {>_ {1_ {>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Z.>^Z|>^Z.>^Z|>^Z|>^Z.>^Z|>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Z.>^Zo>^Z|>^Z.>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Zo>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Z|>^Zo>^Z|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9l|=9[|=9l|=9[|=9[|=9l|=9[|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9l|=9N|=9[|=9l|=9[|=9[|=9[|=9[|=9N|=9[|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9N|=9[{w:[{wK[{w-[{w-[{w-[{wK[{w:[{w:[{w:[{w:[{w:[{wK[{w:[{w:[{w-[{wK[{w:[{w:[{wK[{w:[{wK[{w-[{w:[{wK[{wK[{w-[{w:[{wK[{w-[{w:[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w-[{w:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZV*:ZVx:ZV*:ZVx:ZVx:ZV*:ZVx:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZV*:ZVk:ZVx:ZV*:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVx:ZVk:ZVk:ZVk:ZVx95Jx95Jx95Jx95hx95Wx95hx95Wx95Wx95hx95Wx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Jx95hx95Jx95Wx95hx95Wx95Wx95Wx95Wx95Jx95Wx95Jx95Jx95Jx95Wws6WwsGWws)Wws)Wws)WwsGWws6Wws6Wws6Wws6Wws6WwsGWws6Wws6Wws)WwsGWws6Wws6WwsGWws6WwsGWws)Wws6WwsGWwsGWws)Wws6WwsGWws)Wws6Wws)Wws)Wws)Wws6VRg6VRg6VRg6VR&6VRt6VR&6VRt6VRt6VR&6VRt6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRg6VR&6VRg6VRt6VR&6VRg6VRg6VRg6VRt6VRt6VRt6VRt6VRt6VRt6VRt6VRg6VRt51Ft51Ft51Ft51dt51St51dt51St51St51dt51St51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51Ft51dt51Ft51St51dt51St51St51St51St51Ft51St51St51St51St51St51St51St51Ft51Sso2SsoCSso%Sso%Sso%SsoCSso2Sso2Sso2Sso2Sso2SsoCSso2Sso2Sso%SsoCSso2Sso2SsoCSso2SsoCSso%Sso2SsoCSsoCSso%Sso2SsoCSso2Sso2Sso%Sso2Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso%Sso2RNc2RNc2RNc2RN"2RNp2RN"2RNp2RNp2RN"2RNp2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNc2RN"2RNc2RNp2RN"2RNc2RNc2RNc2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNp2RNc2RNp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-`p1-Op1-`p1-Op1-Op1-`p1-Op1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-`p1-Bp1-Op1-`p1-Op1-Op1-Op1-Op1-Op1-Op1-Bp1-Op1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-Bp1-O
```

The easy way to do this challenge is with a tokenised language which doesn't need newlines and ignores invalid tokens.

Tested using [this interpreter](http://www.geocachingtoolbox.com/index.php?page=brainfuckOok)*. Assumes 8-bit cells for extra golfiness. Programs are also overlapped slightly to save some bytes.

<sup>*This interpreter has a strange quirk whereby the last token needs a char after it to be registered, which affects `n = 62`. There's offline 8-bit interpreters without this quirk, but this was the best online one I could find.</sup>

Comment: Well... so much for a race to 95 :|

Comment: I was in the midst of doing something similar in Brainfuck… oh well. Wouldn't have been as good as in Ook!

Comment: I was also working on BF when I realized it didnt work I started looking for BF derivatives.

Comment: Not often we see an improvement of over 5000 bytes in an optimization step... #awkward

Comment: thanks for paying tribute to my language ppl! :)

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 95 programs, <del>2439</del> 2063 bytes

```php
<?=0;die?>;></*na^bkd`m'(:chd>=:=;/)m`]ajc_l&'9bgc=<9<:/(l_\`ib^k%&8afb<;8;9/'k^[_ha]j$%7`ea;:7:8/&j]Z^g`\i#$6_d`:9697/%i\Y]f_[h"#5^c_98586/$h[X\e^Zg!"4]b^87475/#gZW[d]Yf !3\a]76364/"fYVZc\Xe~ 2[`\65253/!eXUYb[Wd}~1Z_[54142&% dWTXaZVc|}0Y^Z43031%%~cVSW`YUb{|/X]Y32/20$%}bURV_XTaz{.W\X21.1/#%|aTQU^WS`yz-V[W10-0."'}`SPT]VR_xy,UZV0/,/-!%z_ROS\UQ^wx+TYU/.+., %y^QNR[TP]vw*SXT.-*-+~%x]PMQZSO\uv)RWS-,),*}%w\OLPYRN[tu(QVR,+(+)|%v[NKOXQMZst'PUQ+*'*(|zuZMJNWPLYrs&OTP*)&)'{ztYLIMVOKXqr%NSO)(%(&zzsXKHLUNJWpq$MRN('$'%yzrWJGKTMIVop#LQM'&#&$xzqVIFJSLHUno"KPL&%"%#w|rUHEIRKGTmn!JOK%$!$"vzoTGDHQJFSlm INJ$# #!uznSFCGPIERkl~HMI#"~" tzmREBFOHDQjk}GLH"!}!~szlQDAENGCPij|FKG! | }spkPC@DMFBOhi{EJF ~{~|rpjOB?CLEANghzDIE~}z}{qpiNA>BKD@MfgyCHD}|y|zpphM@=AJC?LefxBGC|{x{yopgL?<@IB>KdewAFB{zwzxnpfK>;?HA=Jcdv@EAzyvywmrgJ=:>G@<Ibcu?D@yxuxvlpdI<9=F?;Habt>C?xwtwukpcH;8<E>:G`as=B>wvsvtjpbG:7;D=9F_`r<A=vurusjfaF96:C<8E^_q;@<utqtrif`E859B;7D]^p:?;tspsqhf_D748A:6C\]o9>:srorpgf^C637@95B[\n8=9rqnqoff]B526?84AZ[m7<8qpmpnef\A415>73@YZl6;7polomdf[@304=62?XYk5:6onknlch\?2/3<51>WXj495nmjmkbfY>1.2;40=VWi384mliljafX=0-1:3/<UVh273lkhkia\W</,092.;TUg162kjgjh`\V;.+/81-:STf051jifig_\U:-*.70,9RSe/40ihehf^\T9,)-6/+8QRd.3/hgdge]\S8+(,5.*7PQc-2.gfcfd\\R7*'+4-)6OPb,1-febec[\Q6)&*3,(5NOa+0,edadbZ\P5(%)2+'4MN`*/+dc`caZTQ4'$(1*&3LM_).*cb_b`X\N3&#'0)%2KL^(-)ba^a_XRM2%"&/($1JK]',(a`]`^WRL1$!%.'#0IJ\&+'`_\_]VRK0# $-&"/HI[%*&_^[^\URJ/"~#,%!.GHZ$)%^]Z][TRI.!}"+$ -FGY#($]\Y\ZSRH- |!*#~,EFX"'#\[X[YRRG,~{ )"}+DEW!&"[ZWZXQRF+}z~(!|*CDV %!ZYVYWPRE*|y}' {)BCU~$ YXUXVPJF){x|&~z(ABT}#~XWTWUOHC(zw{%}y'@AS|"}WVSVTNHB'yvz$|x&?@R{!|VURUSMHA&xuy#{w%>?Qz {UTQTRLH@%wtx"zv$=>Py~zTSPSQKH?$vsw!yu#<=Ox}ySRORPJH>#urv xt";<Nw|xRQNQOIH="tqu~ws!:;Mv{wQPMPNHH<!spt}vr 9:LuzvPOLOMGH; ros|uq~89KtyuONKNLFH:~qnr{tp}78JsxtNMJMKF>9}pmqzso|67IrwsMLILJE>8|olpyrn{56HqvrLKHKID>7{nkoxqmz45GpuqKJGJHC>6zmjnwply34FotpJIFIGB>5ylimvokx23EnsoIHEHFA>4xkhlunjw12DmrnHGDGE@>3wjgktmiv01ClqmGFCFD?>2vifjslhu/0BkplFEBEC>>1uheirkgt./AjokEDADB=>0tgdhqjfs-.@injDC@CA=4/sfcgpier,-?hmiCB?B@<4.rebfohdq+,>glhBA>A?;4-qdaengcp*+=fkgA@=@>:4,pc`dmfbo)*<
```

Requires the option [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) to be On or some values such as 4096. It defaults to 4096 for the web service (but not CLI) at least for my installation.

The doc says `ob_clean` doesn't return anything. But it returned true nevertheless.

Shifted programs look like these:

```
9:  ...dmfbo)*<ejf@?<?=8+ob_clean();die?>;><8*na^bkd`m(:chd>=:=;/.)...
15: ...dmfbo)*<ejf@?<?=16-ob_clean();die?>;><04*na^bkd`m'(:chd>=:=;...
94: ...dmfbo)*<ejf@?<?=93+ob_clean();
```

Generated using this CJam program:

```
"<?=0;die?>"95,(;{["<?="1$(_Ab:--3={))'-}'+?"ob_clean();die?>"]sf{i\- 95+ 32- 95% ' +}}%s-5<
```

Comment: My first tries were Foo and Gammaplex. Then I realized that I should find a language with 2 or more characters denoting the starting point...

Answer (score 5):

## [CJam](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=0), 10 programs, 1 byte

I thought I'd better add this right off the bat before someone else gets cheeky and does it :P

```
0
```

A CJam program with just a plain number outputs that number, so this is an easy way to get 10 programs that work, namely:

`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, and `9`.

The next program `:` unsurprisingly does not output `10` but gives an "unfinished operator" error.

This undoubtedly works in many languages.

Comment: You can also add MATL to the title of your submission=)

Comment: And Pyth, and GolfScript, and *looooots* of other golfing langs. =) You can just say: "Polyglot".

Comment: Works in non-golfing languages, too. For example, this is completely valid PowerShell.

Comment: Works in Seriously and Actually, also.

Comment: Mathematica too.

Comment: Also Jelly and 05AB1E work too.